# Binarycrossentropy: The lost function does not converge, but rather stagnates at 0.693

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, loss

The `Binarycrossentropy` loss function does not converges.

It stagnates at 0.6933 = `Binarycrossentropy(1.0,0.5) = Binarycrossentropy(0.0,0.5)`.

The net takes 8 images of size 224x224x3 representig a 3d object as input with `batch_size = 16`.

At least I would expect getting the net overfitting, but converge.

I hope someone has a hint for me.
Thank you.

````py
    nets, inputs=[], []
    base_ResNet50 = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top= False, input_shape=(image_size,image_size,channels))
    for layer in base_ResNet50.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    inputs = Input(shape=(views,image_size,image_size,channels))
    pre_images = preprocess_input(inputs)
    for x in tf.split(pre_images,num_or_size_splits=views, axis=1):
        x = tf.reshape(x,[-1,image_size,image_size,channels])
        x = base_model(x)
        x = Flatten()(x)
        nets.append(x)
    out = tf.math.reduce_max(nets, [0])
    out = Dense(100)(out)
    out = Activation('relu')(out)
    out = Dense(10)(out)
    out = Activation('relu')(out)
    out = layers.Dropout(0.5)(out) 
    out = Dense(1)(out)                 
    out = Activation('sigmoid')(out) 
    
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.1)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['accuracy'])

```Epoch 1/50
592/592 [==============================] - 691s 1s/step - loss: 36731256.0000 - accuracy: 0.4958 - val_loss: 0.6938 - val_accuracy: 0.4933
Epoch 2/50
592/592 [==============================] - 724s 1s/step - loss: 0.6937 - accuracy: 0.5042 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_accuracy: 0.5067
Epoch 3/50
592/592 [==============================] - 670s 1s/step - loss: 0.6936 - accuracy: 0.4789 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_accuracy: 0.5067
Epoch 4/50
592/592 [==============================] - 673s 1s/step - loss: 0.6934 - accuracy: 0.4941 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_accuracy: 0.5067
Epoch 5/50
592/592 [==============================] - 670s 1s/step - loss: 0.6934 - accuracy: 0.4823 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_accuracy: 0.5067
Epoch 6/50
592/592 [==============================] - 666s 1s/step - loss: 0.6933 - accuracy: 0.4738 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_accuracy: 0.5067
Epoch 7/50
592/592 [==============================] - 664s 1s/step - loss: 0.6933 - accuracy: 0.4941 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_accuracy: 0.4933
Epoch 8/50
592/592 [==============================] - 673s 1s/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.4924 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_accuracy: 0.4933
Epoch 9/50
592/592 [==============================] - 670s 1s/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.4941 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_accuracy: 0.4933```
````